# Forward Declaration & Functors

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

```
// backgammon.h

#ifndef BACKGAMMON_H
#define BACKGAMMON_H

#include <ctime>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

namespace Backgammon
{

typedef boost::mt19937 Generator;
typedef boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> Distribution;

template<typename Seed, typename Dist>
class roll_six {
  public:
    roll_six(Seed seed) : _seed(seed) {}
    int operator()() { 
      Dist dist(1, 6);
      return dist(_seed);
    }
  private:
    Seed _seed;
};

Generator gen(std::time(0));
roll_six<Generator,Distribution> roll_die(gen);

}

#endif

// backgammon.cpp

namespace Backgammon
{

// INSERT FORWARD DECLARATION FOR DICE FUNCTOR

}
```

The roll_six class simulates a six-sided die as a functor. The difficulty occurs when I try to do a forward declaration for operator()(). I know for backgammon.h, I have to cut-off the function with a semi-colon to show it's a prototype, but what is the proper syntax for the implementation in backgammon.cpp?

Also if it matters, here's the main.cpp:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "backgammon.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::cout << "Lets Play Backgammon" << std::endl;
  int roll = Backgammon::roll_die();
  std::cout << roll << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a bad case of OCD. I'll keep it all in the header file if I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution! Thank you contributors.

```
//backgammon.h

#ifndef BACKGAMMON_H
#define BACKGAMMON_H

#include <ctime>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

namespace Backgammon
{

typedef boost::mt19937 Generator;
typedef boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> Distribution;

template<typename Seed, typename Dist>
class roll_six {
  public:
    roll_six(Seed seed) : _seed(seed) {}
    int operator()();
  private:
    Seed _seed;
};

/* no need to stick it in the .h file
template <typename Seed, typename Dist>
int roll_six<Seed,Dist>::operator()() { 
  Dist dist(1, 6);
  return dist(_seed);
}
*/

extern Generator gen;
extern roll_six<Generator,Distribution> roll_die;

}

#endif

// backgammon.cpp

#include "backgammon.h"

namespace Backgammon
{

Generator gen(std::time(0));
roll_six<Generator,Distribution> roll_die(gen);

template <typename Seed, typename Dist>
int roll_six<Seed,Dist>::operator()() { 
  Dist dist(1, 6);
  return dist(_seed);
}

template int roll_six<Generator,Distribution>::operator()();

}

// makefile

all:
    g++ -o .o main.cpp backgammon.cpp
    ./.o
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got your question right, but did you mean:

```
template <typename Seed, typename Dist>
int roll_six<Seed,Dist>::operator()() { 
  Dist dist(1, 6);
  return dist(_seed);
}
```

As usual, you define a member by explicitly prepending the class name (`RollSix`), and for template classes you have to give the full template parameters to disambiguate eventual specializations.

Keep in mind, though, that this will only *define* the `operator()`, but not *instantiate* it. If you don't add an explicit instantiation in the source file, the operator will not be instantiated and not be available at link time. You can explicitly instantiate it in the cpp file with:

```
template int roll_six<Generator,Distribution>::operator()();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the classes' name is "roll_six", and even so, I still get an error

Comment: main.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `Backgammon::roll_six<boost::random::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32u, 624u, 397u, 31u, 2567483615u, 11u, 4294967295u, 7u, 2636928640u, 15u, 4022730752u, 18u, 1812433253u>, boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<int> >::operator()()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: I did, but then I hit the return key which adds a comment, sorry.

Comment: @JordanJetson: This is precisely the instantiation problem I mentioned in the final paragraph. Added an example of explicit instantiation.

Comment: thank you, does explicit instantiation take place before or after the function in the .cpp?

Comment: @JordanJetson: After. If before, the compiler wouldn't know *what* to instantiate.

Comment: that's what I was thinking, but I did it after and it still has the same problem.

Comment: namespace Backgammon
    {
        
    typedef boost::mt19937 Generator;
    typedef boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> Distribution;
    
    template <typename Seed, typename Dist>
    int roll_six<Seed,Dist>::operator()() { 
      Dist dist(1, 6);
      return dist(_seed);
    }
    
    template int roll_six<Generator,Distribution>::operator()();
    
    }

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to be messy

Comment: I think I'll just skip it and move on and put it in the .h file.

Comment: @JordanJetson: Did you also remember to actually *link* `backgammon.cpp`?

Comment: Dear @thiton, could you explain why we should instantiate `operator()()`? Why not instantiate the whole class `template class roll_six<Generator,Distribution>`? I thought that it will automatically instantiate all inner functions

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure, if I understand you right, but

```
Generator gen(std::time(0));
roll_six<Generator,Distribution> roll_die(gen);
```

should go into *backgammon.cpp*

and in *backgammon.h* you need

```
extern Generator gen;
extern roll_six<Generator,Distribution> roll_die;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is just like when defining some other member function, just that this function is called `operator()`.

```
template<typename Seed, typename Dist>
int RollSix<Seed, Dist>::operator()() 
{
    // whatever it does
}
```

A complication though is that this is a template, so it has to be visible wherever the operator is used. So, putting it in the .cpp file doesn't work. It should be in the header.